# android.net.ConnectivityManager$TooManyRequestsException Error In Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

My application automatically stops itself after a while and this is the error message:

android.net.ConnectivityManager$TooManyRequestsException
com.di.module.ConnectLiveData.onActive

[Play Store Console Feedback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjGb1.png)